# TLS 1.3 not working eventhough everything seems ok

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, nginx, tls1.2

I wanted to give TLSv1.3 a try, here is my situation:

- I'm running nginx 1.15.5 compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.1
- TLS1.3 enabled in the nginx.conf and restarted it
- Enabled TLS draft 28 in chrome flags

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest gives me this:

> Experimental: This server supports TLS 1.3 (RFC 8446).
>
> Protocols TLS 1.3 Yes

If I go to mail.google.com my browser uses 1.3, but on my own server it won't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using Chrome 69 which supports *TLS 1.3 draft 28* but not *TLS 1.3 draft final*

Chrome Beta supports it.

So my setup was actually too new, `mail.google.com` might be using something different or the draft 28 version.

Comment: Have a look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-28#section-4.2.1.1: While the eventual version indicator for the RFC version of TLS 1.3
   will be 0x0304, implementations of draft versions of this
   specification SHOULD instead advertise 0x7f00 | draft_version in the
   ServerHello and HelloRetryRequest "supported_versions" extension.
   For instance, draft-17 would be encoded as the 0x7f11.  This allows
   pre-RFC implementations to safely negotiate with each other, even if
   they would otherwise be incompatible.